# Match alphanumeric string of a specific length and string with hypens using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-4.5

I am parsing a URL and need help matching a an alphanumeric string of a specific length and a string with hyphens.

here is a sample string:

```
http://www.theplace.com/er5465dF3/2288494033cbbbe3de861f60bdf6934c/zRklm2/The-Post-Is-Here
```

This is what I have for the alphanumeric, but it is matching any alphanumeric with that length in the URL:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}
```

I Tired this, but I do not want the slashes back nor is it guaranteed that there will be a slash at the end. So I was a bit closer with this:

```
\/[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}\/
```

I've tried a few things with the hyphen regex, but they were variations of what I had above without the length attribute. I am stumped on that one. Again, it is not guaranteed that the hyphenated string will be at the end or between slashes.

This is what I am expecting as output for each type:

I should only get back one match for  `er5465dF3` with an alphanumeric regex with length of 9.

I should only get back `The-Post-Is-Here` with the hyphen regex.

Comment: what would be the expected output?

Comment: in the second `The-Post-Is-Here` there are 16 characters.

Comment: Can we comment on the down votes?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, that is just an example, it could be longer or shorter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add word boundaries in your regex to does an exact match.

```
\b[0-9a-zA-Z]{9}\b
```

Output:

```
er5465dF3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bY3kJ3/1)

To get the hypen seperated string,

```
\b[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)+\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bY3kJ3/2)